# Warning from RVM on upgrading Rubies

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to upgrade `ruby` on my system (OSX 10.9) via `RVM`.  As I am starting the upgrade process via: `RVM upgrade`, I receive the following warning:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0'.
```

This warning makes me think my `dot` files are not properly configured.

How can I correct this warning?

Comment: make sure to read the message, usually it's just a simple PATH= overwriting the `PATH` set by rvm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add '/Users/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin' to the beginning of your $PATH environment variable :)

To do this (for your user profile only), add the following lines to ~/.bash_profile:

1. PATH=/Users/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:$PATH
2. export PATH